# How to hide a window from desktop after booting in GNOME 3?

Tags: debian, gnome, gnome3

I'm using Debian 10.3 + GNOME 3.

When i start my computer i get opened window of MEGAsync program in desktop.

I can close this window by ESCape key. But this will have to do every time the operating system starts. It is not comfortable.

How to configure automatic removal of this window from the desktop, for example, to tray?
Maybe there is some kind of extension for GNOME 3?

**Addition:**

I need this program to work in the background every time after operating system starts. This program syncronize files with cloud storage.

I need that this program does not appears every time after booting operating system as an open window on the desktop.

[image: Screenshot of desktop with opened MEGAsync program]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!

The extension SimpleTray for GNOME 3 solved my problem:

[extensions.gnome.org/extension/1483/simpletray/](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1483/simpletray/)

Answer (score 0):

You may just remove this program from auto-started applications: see this explanation https://gnomeshell.wordpress.com/2011/08/28/manage-the-startup-applications/

There is also an entry in gnome tweak tool to manage user specific applications at startup https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Tweaks (note: gnome-tweak-tool package is not installed by default).

### Edit after comment:

As you need the program:

- first check if mega client has some command-line option to minimze at startup (look at man page or documentation), and if so alter the command using gnome-session-properties (first link above).
- if no such option, check this solution https://askubuntu.com/questions/663187/how-can-i-run-a-program-on-startup-minimized a bit more tricky, but looks to work... See also this one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1102320/is-there-a-way-to-open-startup-applications-minimized-or-on-a-hidden-workspace-i

Comment: I apologize that not immediately clarified. I need this program to work in the background every time after operating system starts. This program syncronize files with cloud storage.
I need that this program does not appears every time at booting OS as an open window on the desktop.

Comment: I think you gave me wrong link in the "Edit after comment".